# Need Delegate in Razor with two Parameters

Tags: razor, delegates

I have the following syntax in a .cshtml page:

```
 @cell(<Class object>)
```

And is defined like this in the header:

```
 Func<dynamic, object> cell =
 @<........>;
```

How can I define the cell Func so that I can send it an int parameter, like this?

```
 @cell(<Class object>, intNum)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 ways:

first one, the clever way: make a class type that contains at least 2 properties, the original Class and the int number that you need. and then access them.

second one: 
the proper way of razor delegate:

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2012/01/26/templated-razor-delegates-combined-with-partial-views.aspx

Use delegates is not necessary unless you need to pass html code to an htmlhelper extension.
Maybe you need to use a @helper function and conserve html inside a cshtml file.